# Оптимизация алгоритма загрузки данных, посоветуйте в какую сторону смотреть

Tags: алгоритм, оптимизация, 1с

Хочу оптимизировать алгоритм загрузки данных. Имеем следующее: эксель в котором содержится информация по заявкам. Данные выгружаются с начала года по текущую дату. Одна заявка, одна строка. В заявке указывается несколько ключевых значений: контрагент, филиал на котором в данный момент заявка, ун. идентификатор, статус и др. информацию. При этом тот же статус или филиал может меняться со временем.

В системе (1с) по каждой заявке создается отдельный документ. Текущая версия загрузки считывает эксель в виртуальную таблицу и затем построчно её обрабатывает, проверяя каждую заявку из файла. Если заявка была создана ранее, проверяется изменение данных. При этом присутствуют"классические" для 1с решения типа запросов в цикле(для каждой заявки выполняется три четыре запроса). Сейчас загрузка занимает часа три где-то для 10 тыс. заявок. Предполагаю что к концу года время вырастет ещё больше.

Пока вижу такой вариант - получение ссылок на справочники(контрагенты, филиалы) через промежуточные виртуальные таблицы. Должно ускорить ситуации, когда на одном контрагенте несколько заявок.

Как дополнительный вариант - создание отдельной базы, в которой будет хранится информация из предыдущей загрузки. В теории позволить сопоставлять текущий и предыдущий набор данных, и в основную базу толкать только новые и те по которым произошли изменения.

Кто что может посоветовать по поводу всего перечисленного?

Comment: Довольно странный способ читать заявки - из Excel. Как минимум тут сразу бросается в глаза, что сама таблица по заявке должна бы как то сообщать Вашему софту, что было изменение по строке. Какой то "виртуальный параметр - столбец", завязанный на VBA например или что то подобное. В этом случае Вы существенно сократите число запросов в базу.

Comment: Я бы поставил вопрос в проекте об устранении Excel из этой цепочки. Лучше поднять какой то свой сервис, который будет умнее например, и делать изменения в базе или "заранее", с последующей валиадацией и акцептом, или же сразу же, в режиме онлайн, если это приемлимо. В этом случае даже всю историю изменений довольно легко сохранить и например давать люлей ответственным по заявкам при необходимости... (доп. функцинал)

Comment: Можете еще хранить в базе хэш всех параметров для каждой из строк. Считать  его при получении из Excel, и сравнивать с тем что в базе. Если не совпал - было изменение. Делается одним SQL запросом. А если подгрузить ОЗУ вашей машинки, то сразу на много строк.

Comment: Как понимаю, у вас по каждой строке отдельные запросы для поиска данных по заявке. Тяжело судить, не видя всей картины. Если так, то надо переписывать все на один запрос.

Comment: @Sagittarius без хэша этот запрос сильно нагрузит систему. Но работать будет точно быстре.

Comment: @ProtectchildrenofDonbas2014, нет ясности в том, какие данные сопоставляются для выявления изменений. Если статус и филиал, то запросом можно сделать сверку на отличие данных. Но тут много нюансов. Задача очень поверхностно сформулирована.

Comment: @ProtectchildrenofDonbas2014 - Excel убрать не выйдет, но ваш ответ подтвердил жизнеспособность идеи с промежуточной базой, с помощью которой можно будет выделить заявки по которым были изменения

Comment: @Sagittarius - идея с запросом интересная, посмотрю как это можно реализовать, используя специфику платформы. Сейчас данные подготавливаются в виртуальной таблице, и затем сравнение полей идет через if, но это стандартная практика платформы.

Comment: @kio вам точно надо помнить, что единый запрос с множеством сравнений может работать медленно. Зря игнорируете hash.

Comment: Прежде чем что то менять, надо запустить загрузку с замером производительности. Потому что может оказаться, что ничего менять не надо, а проблема в конкретном запросе ...

Comment: @santavital запросы примитивные, и по замером было определено что условно на каждую строку выполняется от трех до четырех запросов. Переделав часть логики, удалось сократить количество выполняемых запросов до 2 максимум на одну строку.

Answer (score 2):

Учитывая советы из комментариев, удалось ускорить выполнение ориентировочно в три раза(с трех часов до одного).
Сделал следующее:

1. Сделал промежуточное хранилище исходных данных(регистр), загружаемых из файла. В него добавлен флаг изменения. При загрузке файла, флаг сбрасывается в двух случаях - это новая запись либо что то изменилось относительно предыдущей.
2. Заявки создаются либо изменяются только по тем записям, у которых сброшен флаг в промежуточном хранилище.
3. В запросе данные группируются по филиалу и контрагенту. Это также ускорило обработку(ранее если шло подряд три заявки от одного контрагента, запрос на получение ссылки на справочник вызывался три раза, сейчас один раз для группы).

Вариант с хешем пробовал, но особого выигрыша по времени не получил. Также в дальнейшем в планах отказаться от экселя и перейти на xml, это также позволит выиграть время.